# Angular and Rails API data passing conventions

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I currently have a website that receives json data from a rails api.  I compare form data with an array of data from the api.  I've implemented the comparison logic in Angular, and I'm wondering if it would be more appropriate to have the comparison logic done via the api by sending data back in an http request.  It seems like a waste of time if the comparison can be done on the front end, but I'm new to api's.  Is either way more conventional than the other?

Comment: It depends what your goal is. If the comparison is important to the back-end application logic, it is absolutely essential that the back-end perform the comparison because the front-end code can be changed by any user (i.e. users can disable the comparison). Having the comparison in the front-end is much better for performance, but you might have to duplicate the logic. In the end, it depends on the use case. Could you share more about what you're trying to do?